# Syncing opened Safari tab groups between devices

Tags: ios, icloud, safari, mobile-safari, tabs

If I have two iPhones/iPads, should I be able to see the same Safari tab groups on both of them? Based on what I have seen online, it sounds like I should. However, it does not seem to be the case for me. I am using the latest iOS 15.4.

The only relevant setting I can think of is `Settings > [name] > iCloud > Safari`, which is turned on. I tried toggling it on and off, but that did not seem to help.

Maybe I am just looking in the wrong place? Is there a screenshot available somewhere?